# ¿Cómo mostrar imágenes en mi aplicación web desde mi servidor SFTP?

Tags: java, primefaces

Tengo imágenes almacenadas en mi servidor `SFTP`, deseo mostrarlas en mi aplicación `web` sin descargarlas al proyecto ni a la computadora. Estoy usando `primefaces` y `JAVA`. Estaba pensando que tal vez desde un **link** pero no sé como implementarlo.
Agradecería me dieran alguna idea.

Comment: NO se que es SFTP, pero si se como puedes mostrar las imagenes sin tenerlas almacenadas en un pc o en tu proyecto, podrias usar un repositorio en linea por ejemplo Amazon S3 (parte de AWS), ahi puedes almacenar y leer las imagenes y mostrarlas con su link. AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/ Componente que debes usar de primefaces (GraphicImage):  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml